# error in verilog : warning using System verilog 'N bit vector?

Tags: verilog

I am using the Icarus compiler, and I'm doing a Mux 4:1.

The code is:

```
module mux (in,out,select);

input   [3:0] in;
input   [1:0] select;
output  reg out;

always@(select or in)
begin
    if (select == 2b'00)

        out = in[0];
    end 

    else if (select == 2b'01)
    begin
        out = in[1];
    end

    else if (select == 2b'10)
    begin   
        out = in[2];
    end

    else if (select == 2b'11)
    begin
        out = in[3];
    end

end
endmodule
```

But, I get this message from the compiler:

[image]

Is the problem because I'm using bit format inside "if" expression instead of "int" expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are writing `2b'00` instead of `2'b00` and Icarus is getting confused thinking you are writing SystemVerilog code, which is not correct either. So either fix your literals, or write your code more efficently as Morgan has posted.

Comment: thank you to you as well dave. The question is I'm not able to understand the " out =in[select]" statement. I don't know how the brakets works here.

Comment: Instead of a fixed index like `in[0]`, you can specify a variable index, and it will use the value of `select` as the index.

Answer (score 1):

Try (with verilog 2005 or later):

```
module mux (  
  input       [3:0] in,
  input       [1:0] select,
  output  reg       out
);
  always @* begin
    out = in[select];
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thank you morgan. But two questions :  What does "out =in [select] means ?, and second one : what would be the difference between " always@* " and "always @ (in or select)" ?

Comment: `out =in [select] ` means use `select` to choose the bit of in that is used for out. standard array selection in other languages. means the same as you `ifelse` whcih could also be written as `case` statment.

Comment: Manual Sensitivity lists are frowned upon these days. As they can lead to RTL and synthesised gate level simulation mismatch.

Comment: @Morgan I prefer `always_comb` than `always@*`. In this example both will work but the latter is much safer. @NIN You can read about the differences here: [Diff between always_comb and always@*](http://invionics.com/systemverilog-insights-always-and-always_comb-are-not-the-same/)

Comment: @DawidGrabowski I agree, that is system Verilog though.

Comment: @Morgan Yes, but Icarus, I think, should support at least this one. And of course I meant the former one is much safer.